# How do I loop through an array of objects to add objects for missing values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a bar chart with data filtered by week (Sun-Sat). However, when a "day" is missing I get an empty space in the graph and I would like to fill that day with the value of "0".

Code and data:

```
const data = [{value: 2, createdDate: "20201025", day: "Sun" }, {value: 7, createdDate: "20201027", day: "Tue", {value: 5, createdDate: "20201028", day: "Wed"}];

const startOfWeek = moment().startOf('isoWeek');
const endOfWeek = moment().endOf('isoWeek');
const currentWeek = data.filter((e) => moment(e.date) >= startOfWeek && moment(e.date) <= endOfWeek);
```

How do I add Mon, Thu, Fri, and Sat with values of 0 to the currentWeek array?

Comment: what should createdDate be filled? nothing?

Comment: Is the moment function coming from the momentJS library?

Comment: createdDate does not need to be filled and yes moment is coming from the momentJS library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array of weekdays you want to test:

```
const weekdays = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
```

Loop through them, adding a "zero" event to `currentWeek` whenever it doesn't contain that weekday:

```
weekdays.forEach( function(weekday) {
  let found = false; // assume
  for ( var i=0; i < currentWeek.length; i++ ) {
     if ( currentWeek[i].day == weekday ) {
        found = true;
        break;
     }
  }

  // weekday isn't in currentWeek, so add it:
  if ( ! found ) {
     currentWeek = currentWeek.concat( { value: 0, day: weekday } );
  }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you could think it from another perspective.
First you fake an array of each day like below:

`{value: 0, createdDate: "20201001", day: "Sun" }`

After that you can merge two array together.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of your days in the array doesn't matter, this is how I would do it:

```
// create an array of short weekdays from moment
const weekdays = moment.weekdaysShort();

// iterate over the days
for (const day of weekdays) {

  // check if this day does not exist in the current week
  if (!currentWeek.find(el => el.day == day)) {

    // if not, add it
    currentWeek.push({value: 0, day});
  }
}
```

[A fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c95tqadz/2/) example